# 2.23 - Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected

Tags: ios

My app got rejected from apple for three times for the below issue,

My app was using offline purpose, so am storing the downloaded files in our document directory, so as per Apple suggestion am calling the method for backup key disabling process for an every document directory calling process, even though my app got rejected from apple now also,

Apple Statement for my app rejection is as follows,
2.23 - Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected
Thank you for making these modifications. Upon further review, we found that your app is not in compliance with our guidelines.

2.23 Details

On launch and content download, your app stores 27.78 MB, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

Next Steps

Please verify that only the content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc. is backed up by iCloud as required by the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. Also, check that any temporary files used by your app are only stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to remove or delete the files stored in this location when it is determined they are no longer needed.

Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because users expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCRUFLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

Please help me on this.

Please find my code for back up key process enabling from below.

Please find my below code ( which is using for back up key disabling process )

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL  {
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil)  { // iOS <= 5.0.1 const char*
        filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
        const char*attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    }
    else { // iOS >= 5.1
        NSLog(@"DB Back up called : DB path : %@",URL);
        NSError *error = nil;
        [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
        return error == nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 1):

The document directory is intended to be used for user-generated files (ie, documents). You can put your data in a few different places, but if you're downloading a chunk of content that you want to keep around while offline, consider using the **caches** area, which isn't backed up by default anyway, and the system can purge if it needs to, so be prepared to redownload as necessary. (The temp directory is prone to much more frequent purging, so I wouldn't recommend it unless the data is downloaded on every app launch anyway.)

You can get the path to it with:

```
NSString * cacheRoot = 
    (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES))[0];
```

[More on app filesystem here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) You may also want to put it somewhere else in the `Library` area if it has a more permanent nature.

Comment: NEVER store your **database file** in `Caches` directory!!!! iOS cleans them up when lacking of free space. So one day your users will be pretty surprising not to see their data in your app!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge your **downloaded file should be store other then Document Directory**,You have to download files in cache or somewhere else instead of Document Directory, Because Document directory data would be store in iCloud so that means all your downloaded data stored in user iCloud account and reduce iCloud storage space this is an one of the reason that your application was rejected by apple.

Comment: The temp directory should only be used for data that is truly temporary (ie, used within the same run of the app). Keeping data for offline use per the OP suggests cache or somewhere else in Library, not temp.